# telnet: why application doesn't read .telnetrc?

Tags: telnet

My telnetrc

```
mode character
```

when i did a connection is not mode character as I put on telnetrc,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You both need to have the name of a remote host, and add blank spaces before the commands. DEFAULT is a valid system name, as it will apply the following commands to every system.

According to the [documentation](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osf1/4/telnetrc/) :

> The first line is the name of a remote host. The subsequent lines must begin with blank spaces, and contain telnet subcommands.

> To specify subcommands that apply to all systems, create an entry, using the word "DEFAULT" as the system name, and specify the telnet subcommands in the subsequent lines.

Example :

```
DEFAULT
     mode c
hostname
     set echo
```

Here, if you connect to 'hostname', telnet will apply both `mode c` and `set echo`, and if you connect to any other system, it will only apply `mode c`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found,DEFAULT doesn't work

```
DEFAULT
mode character
```

no DEFAULT,doesn't work anyway

```
mode character
```

this work(of course put your host or ip instead of localhost)

```
localhost
    mode character
```

EDIT: this is not a solution, only a workaround

Comment: what made you try that to get your telnetrc to work?  which telnet client are you using?

Comment: The standard telnet client installed on Slackware

Comment: No, DEFAULT works, it's actually the blank spaces that you're missing.